# Get Current date time in UTC using XSLT version 1

Tags: xslt-1.0, xalan, exslt

I am using

```
<xsl:with-param name="value" select="date:date-time()"/>
xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" extension-element-prefixes="date" date:doc="http://www.exslt.org/date" version="1.0">
```

I am getting this output

> "event_datetime_utc":"2020-11-22T12:25:32+05:1800000"

How to get Z (ZULU) at end without the +05:1800000 offset?

Comment: Where in the world do you get a timezone offset of +05:1800000 ???

Comment: No idea why I got this

Comment: I don't see how that's possible. In any case, it is not a correct result and I don't know how you can work with it. I have posted a solution for converting a **valid** dateTime to UTC here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64963722/convert-datetime-to-utc-gmt-using-pure-xslt-1-0/64963723#64963723